# Rails upload large file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran into some difficulties while uploading larges files using rails 5.

File is uploaded using ajax and simply grab inside a rails controller.

Used server is : puma.

The file transfer is speed (followed by ajax xhr progress, in a local network (Gigabit)).

But the save of the file /tmp/RackMultipart* took a long time.

I suppose that the file is loaded in memory by Rack, that process and save it in /tmp/. After that, the controller is proceed.

The code work perfectly for small files like images.

But for large file > 100 Mo the completed execution take around 1 minute ...

My code :

The upload area :
views/_attachments.html.erb

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="card-header">
         Fichiers
    </div>

    <div class="card-block">
        <span id="attachment-area-message"></span>
        <div id="attachment-area">
            Déposez vos fichiers ici
        </div>
        <!-- Area for progress bar -->
        <div id="progress-wrapper"></div>
        <script>
            var attachment_token = '<%= form_authenticity_token %>';
            var attachment_model_name = '<%= fileable.class.name %>';
            var attachment_model_id = '<%= fileable.id %>';
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="card-block">
        <div  class="attachfiles-wrapper">
            <div id="attachfiles">
                <% fileable.attachments.includes('user').order(created_at: :asc).each do |attachment| %>
                        <%= render partial: 'app/attachments/attachment', locals: { attachment: attachment } %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS file which launch the upload :

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

    new Clipboard('.btn-clipboard');

    var upload_mime = [ 
        'application/zip',
        // Image
        'image/png',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/tiff',
        'image/svg+xml',
    ];
    var upload_maxSize = 3000000000;
    var server_url = '/app/attachments/upload.js'; // Route for upload file, .js for the js call back

    var element = $("#attachment-area");

    //     EVENTS
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    element.on('dragover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    element.on('dragenter', function(e) {
        element.addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    element.on('dragleave', function(e) {
        element.removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    element.on('drop', function(e) {
        element.removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
            if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
                console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
                upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
            }
        }
        return false;
    });


    //     UPLOADS
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var upload = function(files) {

        // Send each file
        $.each(files, function(key, file) {

            // TEST THE FILE
            // ----------------------
            var FileValidate = true;

            // Size
            if(file.size > upload_maxSize) {
                $('#attachment-area-message').append(file.name + " : Fichier trop lourd (3 Go maximum) : " + file.size);
                FileValidate = false;
            }

            // Mime type
            if( upload_mime.indexOf(file.type) == -1 ) {
                $('#attachment-area-message').append( file.name + " : Type de fichier non authoris&eacute; : " + file.type);
                $('#attachment-area-message').append( "<br>Essayez de zipper le fichier");
                FileValidate = false;
            }

            if(!FileValidate) return true; // Continue to next iteration

            // SEND FILE
            // ----------------------
            console.log(file); 

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('attachment[file]', file );
            formData.append("attachment[model_name]", attachment_model_name);
            formData.append("attachment[model_id]", attachment_model_id);

            console.log(formData);

            // Progress Bar Name
            var progress_name = file.name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'-').toLowerCase();

            // Send the request :)
            $.ajax({
                url: server_url,
                data: formData,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', attachment_token);
                    console.log('BEFORE SEND');
                },
                contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
                processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS

                xhr: function() {

                    // create an XMLHttpRequest
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    console.log('xhr');

                    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                        console.log('xhr progress');
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            var percente = Math.round( ( e.loaded * 100 )  / e.total );
                            $('.' + progress_name + ' .progress-bar').width(percente + "%");
                        }
                    };

                    xhr.onloadstart = function (e) {
                        console.log('xhr onloadstart');
                        $('#progress-wrapper').append('<div class="' + progress_name + '" style="margin-top:5px;">'
                        + '<span class="description">' + file.name + '</span>'
                        + '<div class="progress" id="file-upload-bar">'
                        + '<div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width:0%; height:10px;" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>'
                        + '</div></div>');

                    };

                    xhr.onload = function (e) {
                        console.log('xhr onload');
                        if (xhr.status === 200) eval(xhr.responseText); // Grab the return of rails controller (format.js)
                    };

                    xhr.onloadend = function (e) {
                        console.log('xhr onloadend');
                        $('.' + progress_name).remove();
                    };

                    return xhr;

                }
            });

        });

    };
});
```

And the controller :

(Attachment model is polymorphic base on fileable).

```
class App::AttachmentsController < AppController

    before_action :find_fileable

    def upload

        # Get the File
        uploaded_io = attach_params[:file]

        logger.debug '---------'
        logger.debug params.inspect
        logger.debug '---------'

        # Define file destination
        dest = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'attachments', attach_params[:model_name], attach_params[:model_id], uploaded_io.original_filename)
        file_name = uploaded_io.original_filename
        file_basename = File.basename(uploaded_io.original_filename, '.*')
        file_extname = File.extname(uploaded_io.original_filename)

        # Make dir
        dir = File.dirname( dest )
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless File.directory?(dir)

        # Test if file exist (and update version if needed)
        if File.exist?(dest)
            version = 0
            loop do
                version += 1
                file_name = file_basename + '-' + version.to_s + file_extname
                dest = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'attachments', attach_params[:model_name], attach_params[:model_id], file_name )
                break if !File.exist?(dest)
            end
        end

        # Copy file to dest
        #FileUtils.cp uploaded_io.path, dest
        File.open( dest, 'wb') do |file|
            file.write(uploaded_io.read)
        end

        # Save in database
        @attach = @fileable.attachments.new
        @attach.user_id = @current_user.id
        @attach.name = file_name
        @attach.size = uploaded_io.size
        @attach.mime = uploaded_io.content_type
        @attach.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @attach.save
                flash[:success] = "Fichier ajouté"
                format.js # upload.js callback add new file to the list of files

            else
                flash[:warning] = "Fichier non enregistré :("
            end
        end
    end

    private

        def attach_params
            params.require( :attachment ).permit( :model_id, :model_name, :file )
        end

        def find_fileable
            @fileable = Task.find_by_id( attach_params[:model_id] ) if attach_params[:model_name] == 'Task'
        end

end
```

I have tested different file management solutions : CarrierWave, Shrine, ...

Unfortunately the problem is still there. Always the rack save in front.
Any help or any idea ? I want to eat this "Rack"

Thanks,
Seb.

Comment: Is the problem that the upload takes too long or that it doesn't complete?

Comment: Hi aaron. The upload complete after few minutes. The problem is the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Rack multipart parser writes to disk (that's the fast part), but that its implementation is slow and expensive (see [rack/rack#1075](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1075)). However, the Rack master has huge performance improvements to the multipart parser, so using master should solve your problem.

```
gem "rack", github: "rack/rack"
```

We can verify this by running the following script:

```
require "rack"
require "rack/test_app" # https://github.com/kwatch/rack-test_app
require "benchmark"

app = -> (env) do
  puts Benchmark.realtime { Rack::Request.new(env).params } # trigger multipart parsing
  [200, {}, []]
end

File.write("file.txt", "a" * 100*1024*1024)

test_app = Rack::TestApp.wrap(app)
test_app.post("/", multipart: {file: File.open("file.txt")})
```

Rack 2.0.3:

```
$ ruby multipart.rb
62.617582999984734
```

Rack master:

```
$ ruby multipart.rb
0.3564810000243597
```

Comment: Hi janko, Thanks for your answer. I was trying to test activestorage (new gem for the 5.2 version ...). I will test rack master now.

Comment: THANKS a Lot Janko ! 
For a file around 130 Mo, with older rack version : 1 min 40
, with rack master : 6 secondes. You save me

Answer (score 0):

I have test with chunk method. Create part of 1 Mo of my file and send them in binary. It's better but not the perfection.
With this method rails do not create a MultiRack* file in tmp, but it use memory in both sides, server and client.

The javascript file :

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

    new Clipboard('.btn-clipboard');

    var upload_url = '/app/attachments/upload'; // Route for upload file, .js for the js call back
    var upload_part_url = '/app/attachments/upload/part/';
    var upload_mime = [ 
        'application/zip',

        // Vidéo
        'video/mp4',
        'video/mpeg',
        'video/x-flv',

        // Audio
        'audio/mpeg',

        // Image
        'image/png',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/tiff',
        'image/svg+xml',

        // Text
        'text/csv',
        'text/html',

        // Application
        'application/pdf',
        'application/msword',
        'application/excel',
        'application/mspowerpoint',

        // Adobe
        'application/vnd.adobe.indesign',
        'application/x-indesign',
        'application/indesign',

        'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop',
        'application/x-photoshop',
        'application/photoshop',
        'application/psd',
        'image/psd',

        'application/illustrator',
        'application/postscript'
    ];
    var upload_maxSize = 3000000000;

    //     EVENTS on DROP AREA
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var element = $("#attachment-area"); // Drop area
    element.on('dragover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    element.on('dragenter', function(e) {
        element.addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    element.on('dragleave', function(e) {
        element.removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    element.on('drop', function(e) {
        element.removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
            if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {

                // We upload the files
                $.each(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files, function(key, file) {

                    // Test the file
                    var FileValidate = true;

                    // Size
                    if(file.size > upload_maxSize) {
                        $('#attachment-area-message').append(file.name + " : Fichier trop lourd (3 Go maximum) : " + file.size);
                        FileValidate = false;
                    }

                    // Mime type
                    if( upload_mime.indexOf(file.type) == -1 ) {
                        $('#attachment-area-message').append( file.name + " : Type de fichier non authoris&eacute; : " + file.type);
                        $('#attachment-area-message').append( "<br>Essayez de zipper le fichier");
                        FileValidate = false;
                    }

                    // Begin the upload
                    if(FileValidate) upload(file);
                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    //     UPLOAD
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var upload = function(file) {

        console.log(file);

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("attachment[model_name]", attachment_model_name);
        formData.append("attachment[model_id]", attachment_model_id);
        formData.append('attachment[file_name]', file.name );
        formData.append('attachment[file_size]', file.size );
        formData.append('attachment[file_mime]', file.type );

        // Progress Bar Name
        // var progress_name = file.name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'-').toLowerCase();        

        // Send the file infos
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Request events
        req.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            console.log('xhr progress');
        };

        req.onloadstart = function (e) {
            console.log('xhr onloadstart');
        };

        // Error
        req.onerror = function (e) {

        }

        // Success
        req.onload = function (e) {
            console.log('xhr onload');
            if (req.status === 200) {
                attach = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                if(typeof attach.id !== 'undefined') uploadFileData(file, attach.id ); // Send the data
            }
        };

        // Complete
        req.onloadend = function (e) {
            console.log('xhr onloadend');
        };

        // Send the file infos Request
        req.open("POST", upload_url);
        req.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', attachment_token);
        req.send(formData);

    };


    //     UPLOAD FILE CHUNKS
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var uploadFileData = function(file, id) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Process after the file is read
        reader.onload = function (e) {

            var chunkSize = 1*1024*1024;
            var buffer = this.result;
            var fileSize = buffer.byteLength;
            var segments = Math.ceil(fileSize / chunkSize);
            var count = 0;
            var fileId = id;

            // Send part
            (function sendPart() {

                var segSize = Math.min(chunkSize, fileSize - count * chunkSize);
                var returnFormat = segSize < chunkSize ? '.js' : '.json' ;

                if (segSize > 0) {

                    var chunk = new Uint8Array(buffer, count++ * chunkSize, segSize); // get a chunk

                    // update progress bar

                    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    // Request events
                    req.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                        console.log('part progress : ' + count );
                    };
                    req.onloadstart = function (e) {
                        console.log('part onloadstart : ' + count );
                    };
                    // Error
                    req.onerror = function (e) {

                    }

                    // Success
                    req.onload = function (e) {
                        console.log('part next : ' + count );
                        sendPart(); // Success -> Next part
                    };

                    // Send the file part data

                    req.open("POST", upload_part_url + fileId + returnFormat);
                    req.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', attachment_token);
                    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
                    req.send(chunk);

                }
                else {
                    // hide progress bar
                    console.log("part Done : " + count);            
                }

            })()
        };

        // Read the file
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        reader.onprogress = function(e) {
            // loaded += e.loaded;
            // progress.value = (loaded/total) * 100;
        };

    }
});
```

The controller :

```
class App::AttachmentsController < AppController

    before_action :find_fileable, only: [:upload]

    def upload

        # Define file destination
        model_name = attach_params[:model_name]
        model_id = attach_params[:model_id]
        file_name = attach_params[:file_name]
        file_basename = File.basename(file_name, '.*')
        file_extname = File.extname(file_name)
        dest = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'attachments', model_name, model_id, file_name)

        # Make dir
        dir = File.dirname( dest )
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless File.directory?(dir)

        # Test if file exist (and update version in name if needed)
        if File.exist?(dest)
            version = 0
            loop do
                version += 1
                file_name = file_basename + '-' + version.to_s + file_extname
                dest = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'attachments', model_name, model_id, file_name )
                break if !File.exist?(dest)
            end
        end

        # Save in database
        @a = @fileable.attachments.new
        @a.user_id = @current_user.id
        @a.name = file_name
        @a.size = attach_params[:file_size]
        @a.mime = attach_params[:file_mime]
        @a.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( [Time.now, rand].join )
        @a.completed = false

        @a.save

        logger.debug '----'
        logger.debug @a.to_json
        logger.debug '----'

        render status: 200, json: @a.to_json

    end


    def upload_part

        @attach = Attachment.find(params[:id])

        logger.debug '----'
        logger.debug @attach.inspect
        logger.debug '----'

        dest = @attach.path

        # Copy file to dest
        File.open( dest, 'ab') do |file|
            file.write(request.raw_post)
        end

        logger.debug '----'
        logger.debug File.size(dest)
        logger.debug @attach.size
        logger.debug '----'

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.json { render status: 200, json: { "status": "yop"} }
        end
    end

    private

        def attach_params
            params.require( :attachment ).permit( :model_name, :model_id, :file_name, :file_size, :file_mime )
        end

        def find_fileable
            @fileable = Task.find_by_id( attach_params[:model_id] ) if attach_params[:model_name] == 'Task'
        end

end
```

See you in next episode. I keep searching ...